# how do I use my php file to attach an active url to my output (XML) file

Tags: php, mysql, xml, url, xlink

I have a fairly simple php file that attempts to create an XML document. I am trying to get the URLs pulled from the mysql database to show up in the XML document that i create.

I cannot seem to figure out why my url's are ignored without xlink information. That is the mysql database is accessed successfully but only the title and description information is created in the xml document.

And when I add the xlink information the document simply gives no output at all. The code is below.

```
<?php header('Content-Type: text/xml'); ?>
<?php echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'; ?>
<rss version="2.0">
    <channel xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink>
        <title>METHUZALA.COM</title>
        <link xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://www.methuzala.com">http://www.methuzala.com</link>
        <description>UPDATE: Articles Found and Added</description>
        <language> en-us </language>

        <?php 
            require('php/includes/path.php');
            $conn= mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME );
            $query="SELECT title, short_title, article_url, short_description from  news_article";
            $data = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data))  {
                echo '<item">';
                echo '<title>'.  $row['title']. '</title>';
                echo '<wurl xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="'.$row['article_url'].'" xlink:show="new">TESTING'.'</wurl>';
                echo '<description>'. $row['short_description']. '</description>';
                echo '</item>';
            } //while-end of file
            mysqli_close($conn);
            echo '</item>';
        ?>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

Comment: What do you mean it's ignored? If you look at the resulting XML file, don't you see them?

Comment: the output is missing the link information altogether. instead of 3 lines of output, there are only two.

Comment: I am uploading 5 jpg files that are screen shots of the php code, and three outputs from firefox, chrome(2), and safari browsers.

Comment: You're viewing the output in a web browser? They're for viewing HTML, not XML.

Comment: these browsers have built in rss readers. so the output should  be rss formatted text created from a php file.

Answer (score 0):

When you are opening the `<item>` tag, you have an extra quote...

```
echo '<item">';
```

Should be

```
echo '<item>';
```

This would through out the quoting of data cause all sorts to be combined.

Comment: thanks. i have removed the quote and discovered something interesting. it works in some browsers but not in others.

Answer (score 0):

I welcome any input that might be helpful. I removed the xlink information and this code produces a result that is radically different depending on the browser.

In Chrome: It gives the correct rss XML file output, but no newsfeed output.

In Safari: It gives the correct newsfeed output but it is not formatted. it is one large paragraph.

In Firefox: It gives the correct first lines of the channel(Title of the newsfeed, description of the newsfeed, but no links or elements show in the xml output. Elements are all blank.

```
<?php header('Content-Type: text/xml'); 
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'; ?>
<rss version="2.0">
    <channel>
        <title>METHUZALA.COM</title>
        <link>http://www.methuzala.com</link>
        <description>UPDATE: Articles Found and Added</description>
        <language> en-us </language>

        <?php 
            require('php/includes/path.php');
            $conn= mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME );
            $query="SELECT title, article_url, short_description from  news_article";
            $data = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data))  {
                $title=$row['title'];
                $wurl=$row['article_url'];
                $description=$row['short_description'];
        ?>
        <element> 
            <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
            <link><?php echo $wurl; ?></link>
            <description><?php echo $description; ?></description>
        </element>
        <?php
        }
        mysqli_close($conn);
        ?>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

[firefox output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFljm.png) [safari output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itFCS.png)

Comment: Can you give a sample of the output?

Comment: @nigel ren : added output from safari and firefox to second answer. i am only allowed to attach two files with my status. they are links at the bottom of the very bottom of the code.

Comment: Is this an answer or a continuation of the question?

Comment: I was referring him to the changes I made for his review after his answer to my question...he asked for sample output

Comment: @Rod If this is a clarification of the question, it should be edited into the question, not posted as an answer.